# How to replace a string by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, str-replace

```
const  num_rep = ["A;1", "B;2", "C;3"]; 
const string = 'AABAC.';
```

How to make every "A" become "1", "B" become "2" and "C" become "3"?

Comment: what should be the expected result?

Comment: @NarendraChouhan the string become "11213"

Comment: 1. make a `mapper = num_rep.reduce((r, e) => Object.assign(r, Object.fromEntries([e.split(';')])), {})`
2. replace symbols `[...string].map(e => mapper[e] ?? e).join('')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the simple almost one-liner to replace symbols with another:

```js
const num_rep = ["A;1", "B;2", "C;3"]; 
const string = 'AABAC.';

let num_rep_map = num_rep.map(a => a.split(';')).reduce((p, c) => {p[c[0]]=c[1]; return p;}, {});
console.log(string.split('').map(a => num_rep_map[a]??a).join(''));
```

Comment: How if I want two or more character for the First one just like ,
`const num_rep = ["A;1", "B;2", "C;3","DD;4"]; `

Comment: @user_425 then you need to develop another solution, this one works only for single symbols